# react bootstrap dont collapse after select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

i make a react app with multi-page and use react-router to navigate and react-bootstrap for the navbar
on the phone when i open the navbar and select something the app navigate to that page but the navbar doesn't collapse

code:

```
import React from "react";

import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

//pages
import Pit from "./pages/Pit";
import Techni from "./pages/Techni";
import ViewData from "./pages/ViewData";
import AddComp from "./pages/AddComp";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="primary" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand>ORBIT1690</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/">
                Pit
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/techni">
                Techni
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/viewdata">
                View Data
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/addcomp">
                Add Comp
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Pit />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/techni">
            <Techni />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/viewdata">
            <ViewData />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/addcomp">
            <AddComp />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**tnx for all the helpers**

Comment: Just an idea: it might be that React Router's `Link` catches the `click` event and prevents it from bubbling up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Navbar` `collapseOnSelect` prop is dependent on the `Navbar` `onSelect` prop. However, when a `Nav` item (e.g., your `Nav.Link`), does not have an `eventKey`, the `onSelect` callback will not get invoked and therefore usage of the `collapseOnSelect` prop is futile in this scenario.

To solve this, just add `eventKey` props to your `Nav.Link`:

```
<Nav className="mr-auto">
  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/" eventKey="/">
    Pit
  </Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/techni" eventKey="/techni">
    Techni
  </Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/viewdata" eventKey="/viewdata">
    View Data
  </Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/addcomp" eventKey="/addcomp">
    Add Comp
  </Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

[image: Edit vibrant-villani-8oip7]